Are mathematical journals generally readable for graduated students?
I'm an undergraduate-level self-taught mathematics student. I'm estimating I might be around the second year of the degree on mathematics in terms of general knowledge. While I love the subject, i'm a little puzzled by the state of the art today:
I've been wondering if i've got enough knowledge to read some actual academic publications; but, to my surprise, even with a basic knowledge of fields like analysis, topology, abstract algebra, number theory, set theory, linear algebra, field theory and functional analysis, I couldn't even assess the topic of the publications by reading the title. I don't think the problem is poor titling tendencies, so i'm left with two options:

Academic mathematical journals (like AMS) are far too advanced publications for anyone with anything less than a PhD.
The topics are indeed intractable for anyone but very specialised experts in some specific domain of mathematics.

The first option seems ridiculous to me for a reason: PhDs and masters are supposed to refine the knowledge a student already has (possibly in an specific branch of math), not teaching whole new branches of mathematics with hundreds of sophisticated standard definitions. While PhDs are supposed to have a significantly higher understanding than ordinary graduates, they should at least be able to speak the same language, so to say.
The second option makes way more sense: math is profound, so how sophisticated your research topic  may be depends on your level of expertise in some domain...but that makes me wonder: why would all experts prefer to publish results about specific, particular, almost cryptic subjects for a narrow audience instead of encompassing, insightful results for a more  general audience? Is this some kind of institutional requirement? How is that tendency beneficial for mathematics in the long run? Are mathematical journals generally readable for graduated students?

many of the articles are written by phd students, a part of their thesis, so it stands to reason that other phd students should be able to read them. perhaps not first year candidates though.

“Why would all experts prefer to publish results about specific, particular, almost cryptic subjects for a narrow audience instead of encompassing, insightful results for a more general audience?” Because you need good tools to solve hard problems, and a general audience just doesn’t know these tools – or even the tools that come into creating them, and it’s often several levels of that. And the tools themselves are just that, tools. They’re usually not magic wands: the difficulty, the “depth” remains somewhere – either in developing the tools, or using them.

Please allow a little joke: when you are able to distinguish articles generated by this robot from authentic journal articles you are ready to read the latter.

"PhDs and masters are supposed to refine the knowledge a student already has (possibly in an specific branch of math), not teaching whole new branches of mathematics with hundreds of sophisticated standard definitions." This is generally false, and when it is true it is often true only in a very weak sense: Sure, stable homotopy theory is a refinement of undergrad level algebraic topology in some sense, but the chances of somebody with an undergrad background in topology understanding an article in stable homotopy theory are rather slim.

The situation that you refer to is occasionally illustrated by the contrast in styles between two different answers to the same posted question, here on MathSE.  One of the answers might be approximately 15 lines long, and the other answer might be 200 lines long.  Here, the first answer is actually written for a target audience that has a deep knowledge of the underlying topic, while the second answer is aimed at the hypothetical college freshman.  I speculatively infer that the 14 to 1 ratio in plausible length of the various articles will hold, in published articles.

Although it’s worth mentioning the readability of papers – or lack thereof – is both cultural and subfield-dependent. I personally come from a field well-known for its difficulty and pretty brutal background requirements, mostly because these approaches, however intricate, are the ones that work.

This is what happens when someone who only knows how to drive a car looks under the hood.

@user2661923 ,you would say these articles are generally briefer, with more concentrated information? I suppose that explains the cryptic part.

@user619894 is it common practice to publish in academic journals as part of the PhD thesis?

Articles in research journals are written by specialists in the field for other specialists in the field.
There are publications with papers written for a broader audience.  Ranging from the American Mathematical Monthly to the Mathematical Intelligencer.

Yeah. That makes sense. Those articles were intractable... I'll check out the other publication journals you mention. Thanks!
